# After upgrading to 11.10, when pressing Ctrl+F, Xterm is popping up

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys

Yesterday I upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10. I can't use CTRL+F key combination anymore. It is remap to launch Xterm.

Does anyone know how to remove this mapping? I have never mapped to this key combination and not sure how this came about.

Thanks!

Comment: Hope you'll get a gold badge for this question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The culprit is xbinkeys, a software made to create custom shortcuts. The CTRL+F lauching xterm is an example in the configuration file (~.xbindkeysrc). Since Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't realise it is an example and use it by default, overriding all other uses of CTRL+F.

In order to set things back to normal do as follow :

1. Open your home folder, and press CTRL+H to show hidden files.
2. Open the file .xbindkeysrc (with gedit).
3. Add a pound (#) at the beginning of each line starting with "xterm" and the following one (most probably lines 46-47 and 50-51).
4. Save and exit.
5. Then either logout/login again or restart xbindkeys: `killall -HUP xbindkeys`

Comment: Thanks for the fix. What an idiotic default keybinding for the xbindkeys package to use...

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. I upgraded to 11.10 and installed xbindkeys.

Here is the way that you can fix this problem:

1) Alt-F2 -> type xbindkeys-config -> Run

2) Select two items that are related to xterms and delete them.

3) Click save and quite.

It then works normally as before.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out. I used xbindkeys-config to remove the bad mapping. I am not sure how those came about. Probably I was playing in the past but key combination has changed after the upgrade.