# How to recognize special function keys on keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, microsoft-keyboard

I have a Microsoft Digital Media 3000 Keyboard. None of the function keys or other special keys seem to do  anything, what do I need to do to get them working (at the very least <kbd>F2</kbd>, as not having a shortcut to rename a file is driving me mad)

If I run `xev` and press <kbd>F2</kbd> I get the following output in the terminal:

> KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
> root 0x15d, subw 0x0, time 42858728, (674,456), root:(1034,588),
> state 0x10, keycode 139 (keysym 0xff65, Undo), same_screen YES,
> XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
> XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
> XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
> root 0x15d, subw 0x0, time 42858912, (674,456), root:(1034,588),
> state 0x10, keycode 139 (keysym 0xff65, Undo), same_screen YES,
> XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
> XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: First, are you sure that function keys are enabled? On my keyboard I have a key that enables/disables them...

Comment: @MiJyn I believe so. When I boot into windows on this box, I don't have to do anything special for them to work.

Comment: It seems to be a special keyboard with a different keymapping. I assume that you will have to install a driver (no idea which one though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using xbindkeys and xte you should be able to remap the <kbd>f2</kbd> key.

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys && sudo apt-get install xautomation
```

Create the xbindkeys configuration file

```
xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Now we need to edit the file: `gedit $HOME/.xbindkeysrc`

Scroll to the bottom of the file and create a new line.

Type:

```
“xte 'key F2'” 
0xff65
```

[image]

This *should* bind the f2 function key to <kbd>F2</kbd>. 
Let me know if it doesn't work.

You can do this for any of your keys, just get their `keysym` from `xev`.

Restart the computer.

Comment: Thanks, but F2 still doesn't do rename in file manager. Do I need to reboot to make the change take effect?

Comment: Ah, I forgot a step. Editing now....

Comment: @NikolaiDante Edited.

Comment: Found another mistake :/ Edited. Sorry about that.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll reboot & try again when I get home.

Comment: There is an issue with the xbindkeys example file that mucks up CTRL-F and [binds it to XTerm](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66456/after-upgrading-to-11-10-when-pressing-ctrlf-xterm-is-popping-up), we should delete it from the config file.

Comment: Go ahead and delete those.  So does it work? I have trouble with the function keys sometimes, so I'm wondering if it worked?

Comment: Seems to thanks! RE: the xterm comment, I was more adding it for anyone else hitting the question than anything else as it really confused me for awhile! :o)